Memory usage continuously increases during socket communication with pollset() on AIX
I am managing a server process in an AIX 7.1 environment that performs socket communication using pollset(). We have observed that memory usage(vsz) intermittently increases and fails to decrease, leading to a continuous rise in memory consumption.
This issue becomes particularly noticeable when dealing with data larger than the socket buffer, typically around 100kb.
Initially, we suspected a memory leak and attempted to address it by restarting the process after setting MALLOCOPTIONS=disclaim - an AIX option that promptly returns memory upon free() invocation. However, even after applying this option, the memory usage did not increase.
Given this situation, it seems unlikely that the memory usage increase is caused by a memory leak within the process. If anyone has encountered a similar problem or has insights into troubleshooting memory usage during socket communication on AIX, I would greatly appreciate your advice on resolving this issue. Thank you!


Periodically print mallinfo.uordblks 2. Compile your program on Linux (fix the endianness problems while doing it), then run your program with valgrind: it will show multiple bugs and memory leaks.

